# Finding Points of interest in a specific address or coordinates

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I am willing to find all the existing Points of interest within a specific address.
I have tried to use Google places API, but whenever i type an adress it returns a value in type "Street_address" and not returning more results although there are more points of interests in the specified location. How can i find also the Points of interest and not only the street_address type results,
Thanks :)

I have tried to use the following code:

**Current code:**

```
import googlemaps

googlemaps.Client.extra_params = {"radius":5000}
client = googlemaps.Client('My_Google_Key_ID')
query_string="Maskit 15, Herzliya"
place = client.places(query=query_string) 
all_places=place["results"]
results=pd.DataFrame(all_places)
```

**Expect Rsults: **
Receiving a dataframe containing all the relevant points of interest in the specified address

**Results received: **
A data of type "street_address", not a Point of interest data.

Comment: Have you printed `place` so you can see exactly what is being returned?

Comment: The address is an address.  If you want Points of Interest at (or near) that address use its latitude and longitude and do a [NearBySearch](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) with a small radius (5 km is not small)

Answer (score 0):

### Use Nearby Search of Places API

As mentioned in the comments, you should use [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby) for your use case. The method you are using: `client.places(query=query_string)` is actually using the [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text) of Places API.

If you take a look at the [Reference Documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/#googlemaps.Client.places_nearby) of googlemaps python library, what you should be using is the `client.places_nearby()` method because it is for **Nearby Search**.

Nearby Search have two required parameters:

1. `location`

   - *The point around which to retrieve place information. This must be specified as latitude,longitude.*
2. `radius`

   - *Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. Doing so instructs the Places service to prefer showing results within that circle; results outside of the defined area may still be displayed.*

So for you to be able to search for nearby POIs, let's say within 50,000 meters, you can just query with the `places_nearby()` by converting the address "Maskit 15, Herzliya" into `LatLng` (You can use [Geocoding](https://Maskit%2015,%20Herzliya) here) and use it as the location argument like so:

```
client.places_nearby(location="32.16445126054669, 34.81122036746611", radius="50000")
```

You can also try to specify what kind of POIs you want to return by passing a `keyword` argument like so:

```
client.places_nearby(location="32.16445126054669, 34.81122036746611", radius="50000", keyword="coffee shop")
```

And this should return the results depending on your needs.

Here's a codesnippet that you can try out and check to see if this works for you:

```
# Imports here
import googlemaps
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests

# Enter your own API key here
client = googlemaps.Client('YOUR_API_KEY_HERE')

# I converted the address "Maskit 15, Herzliya" beforehand 
# into coordinates and put it here as an argument in the location parameter.
place = client.places_nearby(location="32.16445126054669, 34.81122036746611", radius="50000", keyword="coffee shop") 
all_places=place["results"]

# I used pandas for now for you to easily check the results
# but you can just convert this to a dataframe like you did before.
pd.read_json(json.dumps(all_places))
```

I hope this helps!